# Creating instances of Inner classes

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, inner-classes

```
class studnt:
    def __init__(self,name,rno):
        self.name = name
        self.rno = rno
        self.laptop = self.laptop()
    
    def show(self):
        print(self.name,self.rno)
        self.laptop.show

    class laptop:

        def __init__(self,brand,cpu,ram):
            self.brand = "ASUS"
            self.cpu = 10
            self.ram = 8  

        def show(self):
            print(self.brand,self.cpu,self.ram)

s1 = studnt("rishabh",100)
s2 = studnt("hanuman",1000)

s1.show()
```

I was learning classes in python and upon executing the code I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classw.py", line 21, in <module>
    s1 = studnt("rishabh",100)
  File "classw.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.laptop = self.laptop()
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'brand', 'cpu', and 'ram'
```

I know its extremely basic question but I am unable to find a solution online

Comment: `def __init__(self,brand,cpu,ram)` requires 3 arguments but `self.laptop()` has passed no arguments.

Comment: [Default argument values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

Comment: Before the instance attribute `laptop` is created, `self.laptop` refers to the class attribute `laptop`, so it's an internal class having a constructor with 3 required parameters (`brand, cpu, ram`). Thus, you have to use something like this: `self.laptop = self.laptop(brand, cpu, ram)` to make your code work.

Comment: "I know its extremely basic question" - *what is the question*? You showed us an error message. Okay? Now what? Does it surprise you? Why? What did you expect to happen? How?

Comment: "I am unable to find a solution online" - did you try [copying and pasting `TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments`](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=TypeError%3A+__init__()+missing+3+required+positional+arguments&ia=web) into a search engine? What happened when you tried that? Do you understand the results you got? Were you for some reason unable to apply the advice? What was the problem?

Comment: you don't write a `show` method but implement `__str__` and/or `__repr__`

Comment: give the `__init__` method default argument values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't put params to laptop `__init__()` method and it should works :D.

```
class studnt:
    def __init__(self,name,rno):
        self.name = name
        self.rno = no
        self.laptop = laptop()

    def show(self):
        print(self.name, self.rno)
        self.laptop.show() 

    class laptop:

        def __init__(self):
            self.brand = "ASUS"
            self.cpu = 10
            self.ram = 8  

        def show(self):
            print(self.brand, self.cpu, self.ram)

s1 = studnt("rishabh", 100)
s2 = studnt("hanuman", 1000)

s1.show()
```

Comment: give the `__init__` method default argument values